# Filtering with regex and .contains in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I often have to filter elements of an `array` of strings, containing some substring (e.g. one character). Since it can be done either by matching a `regex` or with `.contains` method, I've decided to make a small test to be sure that `.contains` is faster (and therefore more appropriate).

```perl6
my @array = "aa" .. "cc";
my constant $substr = 'a';

my $time1 = now;
my @a_array = @array.grep: *.contains($substr);
my $time2 = now;
@a_array = @array.grep: * ~~ /$substr/;
my $time3 = now;

my $time_contains = $time2 - $time1;
my $time_regex    = $time3 - $time2;
say "contains: $time_contains sec";
say "regex:    $time_regex sec";
```

Then I change the size of `@array` and the length of `$substr` and compare the times which each method took to filter the `@array`. In most cases (as expected), `.contains` is much faster than `regex`, especially if `@array` is large. But in case of a small `@array` (as in the code above) `regex` is slightly faster.

```perl6
contains: 0.0015010 sec
regex:    0.0008708 sec
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `perl6 --profile example.p6`

Comment: @BradGilbert Great tool! But I'm afraid I can't interpret the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an entirely unscientific experiment I just switched the regex version and the contains version around and found that the difference in performance you're measuring is not "regex vs contains" but in fact "first thing versus second thing":

When contains comes first:

```
contains: 0.001555  sec
regex:    0.0009051 sec
```

When regex comes first:

```
regex:    0.002055 sec
contains: 0.000326 sec
```

Benchmarking properly is a difficult task. It's really easy to accidentally measure something different from what you wanted to figure out.

When I want to compare the performance of multiple things I will usually run each thing in a separate script, or maybe have a shared script but only run one of the tasks at once (for example using a `multi sub MAIN("task1")` approach). That way any startup work gets shared.

In the #perl6 IRC channel on freenode we have a bot called benchable6 which can do benchmarks for you. Read [the section "Comparing Code" on its wiki page](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/wiki/Benchable#comparing-code) to find out how it can compare two pieces of code for you.